# Draw a neuro-fuzzy network picture in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, graphs

This is a  neuro-fuzzy network picture. I do not know how to draw in LaTeX.

[image]

Thanks to your help, I have drawn the following picture. Than you very much. But, the picture has some minor faults: the size of circles is different； how to adjust the size of text；the picture is a little big;...
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[plain/.style={draw=none,fill=none},
                    net/.style={matrix of nodes,
                        nodes={draw,circle,minimum size=0.8cm},
                        nodes in empty cells,
                        column sep=1.9cm,
                        row sep=-6pt,
                      },
                    >=latex]

    \matrix[net] (mat) {
       |[plain]| \parbox{1.3cm}{\centering Input\\layer} &|[plain]| \parbox{1.3cm}{\centering E\\Function} &|[plain]| \parbox{1.3cm}{\centering H\\Function} &
|[plain]| \parbox{1.3cm}{\centering Output\\layer} \\
        |[plain]|   \\
        |[plain]|   &  {$A_{11}$} \\
        |[plain]|   \\
         {$x_1$} &   {$A_{12}$}&  {$h_{1}$}\\
          |[plain]|   &|[plain]| {\textbf{$\vdots$}}& |[plain]|  \\
          |[plain]|   &  {$A_{1n}$}&|[plain]| &|[plain]|   \\  
           |[plain]|   \\      
         |[plain]|  &  {$A_{21}$} &|[plain]| &|[plain]|\\
        |[plain]|   \\
         {$x_2$} &   {$A_{22}$}&  {$h_{2}$}&{z}\\
          |[plain]|   &|[plain]| {\textbf{$\vdots$}}& |[plain]|  \\
          |[plain]|   &  {$A_{2n}$} \\  
           |[plain]|   \\         
            |[plain]|   &  {$A_{m1}$} \\
        |[plain]|   \\
         {$x_m$} &   {$A_{m2}$}&  {$h_{n}$}\\
          |[plain]|   &|[plain]| {\textbf{$\vdots$}}& |[plain]|  \\
          |[plain]|   &  {$A_{mn}$} \\           
         };
        \foreach \xo in {5}{
        \foreach \aio in {3,5,7}
        \draw[->] (mat-\xo-1) -- (mat-\aio-2);}

 \foreach \xt in {11}{
        \foreach \ait in {9,11,13}
        \draw[->] (mat-\xt-1) -- (mat-\ait-2);}
\foreach \xh in {17}{
        \foreach \aih in {15,17,19}
        \draw[->] (mat-\xh-1) -- (mat-\aih-2);}

        \foreach \ai in {3,9,15}{
          \foreach \hi in {5}
        \draw[->] (mat-\ai-2) -- (mat-\hi-3);}
        \foreach \ai in {5,11,17}{
          \foreach \hi in {11}
        \draw[->] (mat-\ai-2) -- (mat-\hi-3);}
           \foreach \ai in {7,13,19}{
          \foreach \hi in {17}
        \draw[->] (mat-\ai-2) -- (mat-\hi-3);}
        \foreach \hi in {5,11,17}{
        \foreach \z in {11}
        \draw[->] (mat-\hi-3) -- (mat-\z-4);}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: As a start have a look at [chapter 19 of the pgfmanual (v3.0.1a)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page=257).

Comment: Or may be at [neuralnetwork](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/neuralnetwork) package.

Comment: Plenty of duplicates to get you started: [Center/align input nodes in neural network](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/318295) or [Diagram of an artificial neural network](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132444) or [Neural Network representation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40718) or [drawing back propagation neural network](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/162326) or [Drawing neural network with tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153957) or [Drawing a Neural Network architecture](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140782)

Comment: @AlanMunn your comment is the closest thing to an answer this sort of question can get.

Answer (score 2):

### Answer to initial question

One of the things you quickly learn on this site is that there is plenty of good information here which can be found quite easily with a little searching. The following questions should get you started. If you have trouble adapting them to your specific needs, then you can edit your question with a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) of the code you are using and people will be happy to help you then.

- [Center/align input nodes in neural network](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/318295)
- [Diagram of an artificial neural network](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132444)
- [Neural Network representation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40718)
- [drawing back propagation neural network](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/162326)
- [Drawing neural network with tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153957)
- [Drawing a Neural Network architecture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140782)

### Answer to updated question

Here are some adjustments to the sample code you posted.

- set the font in the nodes to `\small`
- set the text width to `1.5em` which will make all the nodes the same size
- set the alignment in the nodes to `center`
- reduced the row spacing a bit (changed to `-.35cm`)

The network you've drawn is quite big, so it's not that easy to make the diagram too much smaller.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[plain/.style={draw=none,fill=none},
                    net/.style={matrix of nodes,
                        nodes={draw,circle},
                        nodes in empty cells,
                        column sep=1.3cm,
                        row sep=-.35cm,
                        text width=1.5em,align=center, font=\small
                      },
                    >=latex,]

    \matrix[net] (mat) {
       |[plain]| {Input\\layer} &|[plain]|  {E\\Function} &|[plain]|  {H\\Function} &
|[plain]| {Output\\ layer} \\
        |[plain]|   \\
        |[plain]|   &  {$A_{11}$} \\
        |[plain]|   \\
            {$x_1$} &   {$A_{12}$}&  {$h_{1}$}\\
        |[plain]|   &|[plain]| {\textbf{$\vdots$}}& |[plain]|  \\
        |[plain]|   &  {$A_{1n}$}&|[plain]| &|[plain]|   \\  
        |[plain]|   \\      
        |[plain]|   &  {$A_{21}$} &|[plain]| &|[plain]|\\
        |[plain]|   \\
           {$x_2$}  &   {$A_{22}$}&  {$h_{2}$}&{z}\\
        |[plain]|   &|[plain]| {\textbf{$\vdots$}}& |[plain]|  \\
        |[plain]|   &  {$A_{2n}$} \\  
        |[plain]|   \\         
        |[plain]|   &  {$A_{m1}$} \\
        |[plain]|   \\
            {$x_m$} &   {$A_{m2}$}&  {$h_{n}$}\\
        |[plain]|   &|[plain]| {\textbf{$\vdots$}}& |[plain]|  \\
        |[plain]|   &  {$A_{mn}$} \\           
         };
        \foreach \xo in {5}{
            \foreach \aio in {3,5,7}
        \draw[->] (mat-\xo-1) -- (mat-\aio-2);}
        \foreach \xt in {11}{
            \foreach \ait in {9,11,13}
        \draw[->] (mat-\xt-1) -- (mat-\ait-2);}
        \foreach \xh in {17}{
            \foreach \aih in {15,17,19}
        \draw[->] (mat-\xh-1) -- (mat-\aih-2);}
        \foreach \ai in {3,9,15}{
            \foreach \hi in {5}
        \draw[->] (mat-\ai-2) -- (mat-\hi-3);}
        \foreach \ai in {5,11,17}{
            \foreach \hi in {11}
        \draw[->] (mat-\ai-2) -- (mat-\hi-3);}
        \foreach \ai in {7,13,19}{
            \foreach \hi in {17}
        \draw[->] (mat-\ai-2) -- (mat-\hi-3);}
        \foreach \hi in {5,11,17}{
            \foreach \z in {11}
        \draw[->] (mat-\hi-3) -- (mat-\z-4);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 1):

Alan Munn provides useful links and there are packages that address this issue, but here's some simple tikz code to get you started.

```
\documentclass[12t,crop]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,1,2} \node[circle,draw] (L\x) at (0,2*\x) {$x_\x$};
\foreach \x in {0,1,2} \node[circle,draw] (R\x) at (2,2*\x+1) {$y_\x$};
\draw[->] (L0)--(R1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]